# How to Embed Spotfire Dashboard into a webpage

Tags: spotfire

I have created a dashboard in the Spotfire Desktop, and now I would like to export this dashboard with all its functionality into a webpage for internal use. How can I do it?

Comment: What, if anything, have you tried from here: https://community.tibco.com/wiki/tibco-spotfire-javascript-api-overview. Also, why are you using a webpage instead of the spotfire web player?

Answer (score 1):

Spotfire Desktop does not support connecting to a Spotfire Server. it's a local-only application.

if you would like to "publish" your analysis to the web, you will need one of the following:

1. a TIBCO Spotfire Cloud account, where you can host any number of dashboards with various data connections and other features
2. an instance of TIBCO Spotfire Server, an instance of TIBCO Spotfire Node Manager, and, depending on what exactly you're trying to do, some development work using the JavaScript Mashup APIs.

Answer (score 0):

Visualizations can be embedded into SharePoint web pages. However, niko is right.  You still need Spotfire server.r